# Does fabric.js provide boolean groups? (subtract, intersect, union, exclude)

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I need to be able to subtract one shape from another using fabricjs.
Could not find anything related to boolean groups their documentation.

Has anyone here written some code to do this?

Comment: Do you need only visual subtraction or mathematical as an area? Do you need to show other shapes under subtraction 'hole'? Please give more details what is the problem and what is expected result. Also, include what you've done so far.

Comment: I guess both. The subtraction needs to visible to the user, as well as having the option of exporting the shape as svg. I admit this question is perhaps premature since I haven't written any code to deal with this.

Comment: is not ready yet but is in roadmap for path objects

Answer (score 0):

In order to show a shape behind a subtract shape you can't use  [globalCompositeOperation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation)

Basically, you can subtract shapes from each other, but you'll need to convert each shape into polygon. For example, deduct triangle from rectangle you will need to create 2 polygons as a triangle and rectangle and do work around to achieve your subtraction. I faced similar issue before (subtract polygons), and I couldn't find anything. So please check my [post on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40515956/7132835) which will give you a guidance how to do subtraction.

Finally, you'll need to create functions which are converting triangles, rectangles, circle, etc. into polygons.

Comment: Seems logical. I will try this. Thank you @Observer.